# Two similar programs both have errors on final line

Tags: c

I have written two similar programs for my programming class.  I have shared the code for both programs due to them being similar in nature and both have compiler issues on the final line with     return0; For the first string of code the error I receive is "expected a declaration" and "syntax error: 'return'". For the second code I receive the errors "return value type does not match the function type" and " 'display': 'void' function returning a value.  I have deleted and added {} at different parts of both codes and tried to rearrange the code. Thanks for help in advance.

Code 1

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define nums 7

void display(int *);

int main()

{


    int channels[nums] = { 2,4,5,7,9,11,14 };
    printf("Channels: ");
    display(channels);
}

void display(int *channels)

{

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nums; i++);

    {
        printf("%d", *(channels + i));
    }
}

return 0;
```

code 2

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define nums 7

void display(int *);


int main()
{

    int channels[nums] = { 2,4,5,7,9,11,13 };
    printf("channels: ");
    display(channels);
}

void display(int *channels)

{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nums; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", *channels);
        *channels++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A good C book might prove helpfull.

Comment: you aren't returning an integer value in either of your `main` functions as your function signature says it should be. also notice how in the second example you have the function 
`void display(int *channels)`
Yet you return an integer value inside of it.

Comment: unrelated note: `for (i = 0; i < nums; i++);` remove last `;`

Comment: To paraphrase Inigo Montoya, "That code - `*channels++`. I do na think it means what you think it means". What are you attempting to do with `*channels++`?

Comment: 1) You do not write the executable statement outside of the function. So remove `return 0;` 2) Do not return value when the return type of function is `void`. So remove `return 0;`

Comment: Learning C straight from a book I am finding rather difficult so I appreciate all the help I have received to better understand this language,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return value is always associated to functions. For example, if a function sums up 2 integers and returns the sum of the integers, it will look something like:

```
int sum( int a, int b ){
    return a + b;
}
```

See here, the return type of the function is `int`, and what it returns is also an `int`, since addition of two integers gives you an integer. It's like 2 horses + 3 horses = 5 horses. You cannot do 2 horses + 3 lions = 5 mangoes. I hope you get the point of return value and type.

Now in code 1, the error is you put your `return 0;` statement out of the `main()` function. The program cannot detect which function is this `return` statement associated to. To correct this, move your `return` statement in the next line after you call the `display()` function, **INSIDE** `main()` function.

Similarly, in code 2, move the `return` statement from the `display()` function to the `main()` function, just as you did in the previous case. This is because `void` expects nothing to be returned, but you are returning an integer. This is the same like giving a millionaire a loaf of break when he says he doesn't need one, he will surely get frustrated!

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  That makes a lot of sense.  I did what you said and it worked. I guess I never put two and two together that the return statement has always gone in main().  Thanks again for the help.